# Jquery click event code firing on some pages, not on others

Tags: jquery

I have the following on several pages of my website:

```
<section class="home-recent" id="read-more-articles">

</section>

<section class="read-more">

  <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="read-more-button" class="read-more-button">Read More</a>

</section>
```

Then, my Jquery code is:

```
$("#read-more-button").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: SdsAjax.ajaxurl,
                data: ({action : 'get_more_articles', offset: offset}),
                success: function(data) {

                  $('#read-more-articles').append(data);
                    offset = offset + 24;
                }
            });

        });
```

This code was working great for a while. Now for some reason, on the home page it doesn't work, but on the other pages it works just fine (literally the same code). I've remove other jquery code and tried to isolate this and also look in the Console. I don't see any errors. I can't figure out why this wouldn't be working in some cases, and not in others. I've spent hours trying to diagnose.

Again the code works. When I put a simple alert(); line inside the click function handler, it doesn't hit on the home page. The click event isn't firing for some reason. On the other pages, it does fire and does execute the alert code.

Comment: is id $("#read-more-button") conflicting somewhere?

Comment: you probably have a duplicate id on the home page

Comment: try to check this id read-more-button appears more than once in one page or not

Comment: I just confirmed there's not another id="read-more-button" anywhere.

Comment: Actually i think you're right. there's a conflict on the button itself. Thanks!